# rsyslogd running but cannot connect on port?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

These are my configuration lines on rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 1029
```

After restarting

I run

```
sudo netstat -taupn | grep syslog
```

and it's running on port 1029

```
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1029          0.0.0.0:*                           24675/rsyslogd
```

I've disabled my firewall and even checked with nmap

but on telnet localhost 1029 -> Gives a connection refused error

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet will only connect to TCP services. You have loaded the `imudp` module, which provides a UDP service.

You could use a tool like netcat (`nc`) to send messages to a UDP socket:

```
nc -u localhost 1029
```